# Failing to remove tweet mention with sed

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I'm taking a look at a twitter dataset and I encountered a problem when trying to remove the mentions from the tweets that have them. I tried the following:

```
echo ' "@user lol I needed it! went to sleep around 3am and woke up around 5 am! lol horrible! "' | \
sed 's/@.*[[:blank:]]//g'
```

My expected output is `"lol I needed it! went to sleep around 3am and woke up around 5 am! lol horrible! "`, however I'm simply getting 2 quotations marks `""`. I find this really weird as the following dummy example works (outputs `"zzz" "dfg"`):

```
echo '"zzz" "@abc dfg"' | sed 's/@.*[[:blank:]]//g'
```

I'm using GNU sed and the database I'm looking at can be downloaded here: [http://help.sentiment140.com/for-students/](http://database%20download%20page). Any ideas of why this might be failing?

Comment: `.*[[:blank:]]` matches *the longest possible string* with a space after it. Nothing in your regex stops the string itself from containing spaces, so everything from the `@` to the last space in the line gets matched.

Comment: ...so, in your case, you probably want to match not `@.*` but `@[^[:blank:]]*`, such that your string can contain *only non-blank* characters.